# vue.js - routing in nested components architecture

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-component, vue-router

I use vue.js to design an administration app and I'm trying to build the UI architecture as modular as possible. So I have set up and wrapped the `Header`, `Body`, `Sidebar` and `Main` in single file components as can be seen below.

**Tree**

```
App
- Header
  - dynamic content
- Body
  - Sidebar
    - dynamic content
  - Main
    - dynamic content
```

**Graphical**

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ HEADER                              SOME DYNAMIC CONTENT │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ BODY                                                     │
│┌──────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────┐│
││ SIDEBAR  │ MAIN                                        ││
││          │                                             ││
││ SOME     │ SOME DYNAMIC CONTENT                        ││
││ DYNAMIC  │                                             ││
││ CONTENT  │                                             ││
││          │                                             ││
│└──────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────┘│
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Now each of these components has it's own router view to display dynamic content depending on the current route. How can I achieve this when I only have one single router-view available in vue.js? Isn't it somehow possible to address these dynamic components altogether through the routed view component without overriding the original content similar to php Smarty, like this?

**aboutus.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <header>
            <header-content>
                About us - Header
            </header-content>
        </header>
        <sidebar>
            <sidebar-content>
                About us - Sidebar
            </sidebar-content>
        </sidebar>
        <main>
            <main-content>
                About us - Main
            </main-content>
        </main>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    /* ... */
</script>
```

But that would be impossible due to the nested architecture I guess? I can't find a proper way to get into this routing architecture in vue.js with nested components.

Comment: I don't think each one should have a router view. Only the main part is where routing happens, the rest should only slightly adapt to the current page.

Comment: You're right about this, that is the general case. But lets say I want to insert a different menu into the sidebar or add a widget to the header based on the current route. Another case would be to drop the sidebar completely in another route thats why I want it to be a single component as well. How would I design an architecture like that?

Comment: I'd just use a couple of `v-if`s if needed for the header/sidebar. I don't think multiple router views are supported in Vue yet: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/213. Angular has something like that, though: https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution without using if-else. Thanks, I will have a look at your links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried achieving something similar to this, in which I have the separate component folder under which I have views folder.
so I imported the component in my index.js. have a look at below example, I have imported admin component under which I have added its children. Similarly, you can add multiple children to the different component and these children will load in their parent component only.

```
{
 path: '/admin',
      component: AdminComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'admin_dashboard',
          alias: '',
          component: AdminDashboard,
          name: 'admin_dashboard'
        },
```

Take a look at this theme structure https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot